# How to get functionality like placing a scene with in a scene in JavaFx 3d

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-8

I've recently started working with javafx 3d. Before that I worked with cocos2dx, a C++ 2d engine. So, In cocos2dx, there is a layer concept, in which we can add elements in layer. This layer has its own coordinate system. So when I add layer inside a layer, the parent layer has its own coordinate system and the child layer has its own. If the position of the child layer is updated/translated, the position of objects inside the child layer also gets updated accordingly. So how can I achieve this kind of functionality in JavaFx 3d. Specifically, I am looking for something like parent and children node in JavaFx 3d, in which parent has its own coordinate system and camera and children has its own. Does javaFx 3d supports this kind of scene arrangement/functionality?, if yes, how can I achieve the same.

Comment: Using multiple cameras in the rendering hierarchy don't make much sense in most cases, since the camera is responsible for a projection from 3D to 2D. As for the layers `Group`s could do the trick...

Comment: Okay, if we leave the camera, do Groups provide a different coordinate system for its children? or is it the standard that in 3d there's always only one universal coordinate system for everything on the scene, (except, subscene). I've this doubt as I am very new to 3d.

Comment: You can apply transforms to the group.

Answer (score 2):

A [SubScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Mipa, So apart from subscene and leaving different camera system, is there any other container in javafx 3d, which provides a different coordinate system (as that of its Parent) for its children?

Comment: Sure. The Group node does. The documentation says: "Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group."